# how to set color of multiple jlabel on click netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlabel

I have multiple JLabels on a JPanel. When I click on JLabel the background changes to green.

I want to make only one label at a time green. For example, if I click on JLabel1 it has to turn green. If I click on another JLabel2, the JLabel1 must turn red and the JLabel2 must turn green.

I have a lot of JLabels and is non-productive to make an event for everyone. I searched a lot but I didn't find anything. I'm using Netbeans 8.1.

The JLabels are declared and initialized. This represents the room map of a hotel.

Declaration of JLabels :

```
 JLabel p401,p402,p403,phol,a301,a302,a303,a304,a305,a306,ahol;
 JLabel d201,d202,d203,d204,d205,d206,d207,d208,d209,d210,dhol;
 JLabel r10,r11,r12,r13,r14,r15,r16,r17,r18,r19;
 JLabel r20,r21,r22,r23,r24,r25,r26,r27,r28,r29;
 JLabel r30,r31,r32,r33,r34,r35,r36,r37,r38,r39;
 JLabel r40,r41,r42,r43,r44,r45,r46,r47,r48,r49;
 JLabel r50,r51,r52,r53,r54,r55,r56,r57,r58,r59;
```

Turn green function :

```
public void click(JLabel l)
{
    l.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            l.setOpaque(true);
            l.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            System.out.println(l.getText());
            getCamId(l.getText()); 
            cam.setText(String.valueOf(idCam));
        }
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply need to:

1. Create 1 method which will handle what happens to a `JLabel` when clicked.
2. Use the `JPanel`'s [`.getComponents()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents--) to get all the components.
3. Use the `instance of` operator to ensure that the component is a `JLabel`.
4. If the component is a `JLabel`, assign the method in `1` as the `click` event handler.

In the event handler, then, simply do the same as above. The event itself should give you access to the `source`, that is the component which triggered the event. You would simply need to do as follows:

1. Iterate over the labels and set them to a green background.*
2. Take the source of the event and set it to red.

*This can be improved by keeping a label which denotes the currently selected label. When a label is clicked, you would reset the background of that label and update it to show the new label which the user has clicked.

Comment: *"Use the JPanel's .getComponents() to get all the components."* or use an array or a `List` or a `Map` or just about any other solution which won't break when you sneeze :P

Answer (score 4):

1. First of all, put all the JLabels into an array or an `ArrayList<JLabel>`.
2. I prefer to use the more flexible ArrayList, and usually create my collection of JLabels inside of a loop, such as a for loop if I know before the loop how many labels to create, or a while loop if I don't.
3. Inside this same creational loop, add the created JLabel to both the `ArrayList<JLabel>` as well as JPanel container that will hold all the labels.
4. That JPanel container should have a decent layout, such as a GridLayout so that it will display the JLabels nicely.
5. All JLabels must be set to be opaque via `myLabel.setOpaque(true)` so that their background colors will show.
6. Create a single MouseListener that all can share, and add it to each label inside the ArrayList.
7. Inside of the MouseListener's mousePressed method, turn all the label's red by using a for loop to iterate through the ArrayList, calling `setBackground(Color.RED)` on each JLabel held in the list.
8. Inside of the same method get the pressed JLabel by calling `JLabel selectedLabel = (JLabel) e.getSource()` on the MouseEvent parameter.
9. After the for loop, change that one selected JLabel's background color to Color.GREEN by calling `setBackground(...)` on it.

If you want more specific help for your code, then you must show your pertinent code.

For example

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LabelGrid extends JPanel {
    // number of columns in the "hallways"
    private static final int COLUMNS = 10;

    // colors of the current selection and the previous selection
    public static final Color PREVIOUS_SELECTION_COLOR = Color.RED;
    public static final Color CURRENT_SELECTION_COLOR = Color.GREEN;

    // Strings for the rooms.
    private String[] pRooms = { "p401", "p402", "p403", "phol" };
    private String[] aRooms = { "a301", "a302", "a303", "a304", "a305", "a306", "ahol" };
    private String[] dRooms = { "d201", "d202", "d203", "d204", "d205", "d206", "d207", "d208", "d209", "d210", "dhol" };
    private String[] rRooms = { 
            "r10", "r11", "r12", "r13", "r14", "r15", "r16", "r17", "r18", "r19", "r20", "r21",
            "r22", "r23", "r24", "r25", "r26", "r27", "r28", "r29", "r30", "r31", "r32", "r33", "r34", "r35", "r36",
            "r37", "r38", "r39", "r40", "r41", "r42", "r43", "r44", "r45", "r46", "r47", "r48", "r49", "r50", "r51",
            "r52", "r53", "r54", "r55", "r56", "r57", "r58", "r59" };

    // array of array, just to simplify
    private String[][] allRooms = {
            pRooms, aRooms, dRooms, rRooms
    };

    // previously selected JLabel. This will be colored RED
    private JLabel previousSelectedLabel = null;

    // ArrayList to hold **all** JLabels
    private List<JLabel> labelList = new ArrayList<>();

    public LabelGrid() {

        // the MouseListener:
        MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();

        // layout for the overall GUI
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        // go through the array of arrays
        for (String[] strings : allRooms) {
            // create a JPanel to hold each "hallway" of JLabels
            JPanel container = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, COLUMNS, 5, 5));
            container.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));

            // iterate through the Strings in the 2nd dimension of our 2D String array
            for (String text : strings) {
                // create a JLabel with the String
                JLabel label = new JLabel(text, SwingConstants.CENTER);
                // make it bigger
                label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
                // make it opaque
                label.setOpaque(true);
                // add the mouse listenr
                label.addMouseListener(myMouse);
                // add it to the arraylist
                labelList.add(label);

                // add it to the container JPanel
                container.add(label);
            }

            // add the container JPanel to the GUI
            add(container);
        }
    }

    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // go through all the JLabels clearing all colors
            for (JLabel lbl : labelList) {
                lbl.setBackground(null); // clear labels
            }

            // color the previously selected JLabel to RED 
            if (previousSelectedLabel != null) {
                previousSelectedLabel.setBackground(PREVIOUS_SELECTION_COLOR);
            }

            // get currently selected JLabel
            JLabel label = (JLabel) e.getSource();
            // set it to green
            label.setBackground(CURRENT_SELECTION_COLOR);

            // make it now the previously selected label.
            previousSelectedLabel = label;
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("LabelGrid");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new LabelGrid());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowGui();
        });
    }
}
```